# 1 out of 2 sticks of RAM stops computer from booting

Tags: windows-7, memory

my computer stopped booting one day for some reason, so I bought a new motherboard, same thing happened, then I bought a new CPU and still happening!

Then when I decided to test the RAM sticks, I found out that 1 of the 2 was the problem. So when I have the problematic RAM taken out, my PC runs fine on its lone 2GB RAM. Both together there's no boot, and the problem RAM on its own still no boot.

I think this was the RAM that I tried to make a partition out of a year ago and is why I have problems.

Is there a way to reformat a RAM? I can't even get to BIOS with the RAM in the PC anyways... so how would that be possible? I checked the RAM stick, there's no burnt pins, everything's perfect...

My RAM is:

PATRIOT DDR2 2GB - 6400 (5-5-5)

Answer (score 6):

You don't partition RAM, you partition hard drives.  There is no formatting of RAM.  You must be confused.

Anyway the bad RAM is bad, there is no fixing it.  It may be under warranty,most RAM has a lifetime warranty.  Try contacting [Patriot](http://www.patriotmemory.com/support/rmap.jsp) and see if they will replace it.

Comment: (This isn't 100% accurate, as you can partition and format a ramdisk... but only until power is turned off.)  Everything else you said I agree with.

Comment: You don't partition or format RAM in a RAM Disk, you partition and format a (virtual) file system which is being held in RAM. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

No.

**Long answer:**

No, but I really suggest you look at some forums/ask questions here before trying to fix something by buying expensive computer parts, unless you don't care about how much you will have to pay.

A good start could be [BIOS beep codes](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm).

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of reasons that RAM can fail ("tried to make a partition out of it" is not one of them, RAM isn't partitioned except for the case of a RAMDISK, and that only lasts until the system is powered down).

None of them can be fixed by a consumer.  (Possible exception: If you're overclocking, the RAM might not actually be failed, it could just not work at that speed.  Try again at the speed the RAM is designed for.)

If it's still under warranty, send it back.  Otherwise throw it out.